# Python recursive function to check if all numbers in a list are even

Tags: python, recursion

This is a question I have to do for a homework assignment. I understand most of it, and the function pretty much works except on one input and I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
def alleven(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        if nums[0] % 2 > 0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
            return alleven(nums[1:])
```

And then:

```
>>> alleven([0, 1, 0])
True
```

I think it's the 1 number that is not processing right, but I'm not entirely sure why?

Comment: For one, you have 2 return functions which I don't think will work. Also you are calling anyeven but the function is declared as alleven

Comment: The line "return anyeven(nums[1:])" is never executed because it's second consecutive return call. Are you sure that described input is the only one that is processed wrong?

Comment: Just remove the `return True` before the `return alleven(num[1:])` and your code should run as expected

Comment: Sorry-- that was a typo on my end

Comment: Just removed return True, and it runs correctly now. Thanks!

Comment: Clarification : the typo was in the last line (return anyeven(num[1:]) but I switched it back to alleven

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_even(counter:int=0, even:int=0, values:list=None):
    if counter == len(values):
        if even == counter:
            return "List is even"
        else:
            return "List is uneven"
    
    if values[counter] % 2 == 0:
        even += 1

    counter += 1
    
    return is_even(counter, even, values)

answer = is_even(values=[0, 1, 0])

print(answer)
```